# Add or set new data to object in Vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to add or update an object in store with Vuex.

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    userData: {}
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_USER_DATA: (state, data) => {
      state.userData.push(data)
    }
  }
})
```

This returns `state.userData.push` is not a function.

And in the components:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="date" v-model="inputData.date1">
    <input type="date" v-model="inputData.date2">
    <input type="number" v-model="inputData.date3">
    <button @click="submitForm">Submit</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapMutations } from 'vuex'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      inputData: {}
    }
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapState([
      'userData'
    ])
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapMutations([
      'ADD_USER_DATA'
    ]),
    submitForm () {
      this.ADD_USER_DATA(this.inputData)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Later on I want to update `userData` with a value from other component, so that it impacts both components. I would like to have a nice way of adding, replacing, concating the old array with a new array. I followed the example in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSexhaiMKJE).

(FYI: I'm currently learning Vue.js from scratch and couldn't figure out this Vuex's mutations, actions...)

Comment: `userData` should be an array and it would be declared as :

         `state: {
           userData: []
          },`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Reason I'm using an object is with an array I can push a multiple array to a `userData` but with an object you can't. If I change `userData.push` to `Vue.set` then it works but later on I can't add or replace an value.

Comment: your `userData` contain the data of one user?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Yes.

Comment: so you could do it simply like : `state.userData=data`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Yes, but that will set the whole object with new values. I'm currently looking for replacing, concating method for this.

Answer (score 4):

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    // userData: {}
    userData: []
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_USER_DATA: (state, data) => {
      state.userData.push(data)
    }
  }
})
```

You are trying to use a `push` method of Object. Object does not have a push method you should initiate `userData` value with Array `[]` or assign that data to the object

Comment: But with Array I can push multiple arrays to it. I'm simply trying to store an Object in state.

Answer (score 4):

if you need reactivity:

```
mutations: {
  ADD_USER_DATA: (state, data) => {
    Object.keys(data).forEach( key => {
      Vue.set(state.userData, key, data[key])
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've ended up using `Object.assign` method.

```
  mutations: {
    ADD_USER_DATA: (state, data) => {
      // state.userData.assign(data)
      state.userData = Object.assign({}, data)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, how would you do this in composition api as a function? And without overriding the data that is already there within state.userData?

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    userData: {}
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_USER_DATA: (state, data) => {
      state.userData.date1 = data.date1
      state.userData.date2 = data.date2
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks for answering, please add some comments and note to make it more clear

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.